# Woocommerce 2 orders communicate

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

If I can get some input here I'd greatly appreciate it. TIA.

I have 2 woocommerce orders. I need order 2 to update the item meta of a specific item id in Order 2 when order 2 order status changes. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

````
function so_status_completed($order_id, $old_status, $new_status)
{

$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$items = $order->get_items(); 

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    // Here you get your data

    $deposititemid = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_deposititemid', true ); 

    wc_update_order_item_meta( $deposititemid, 'Remaining Order Status', $new_status);}}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the code so it works as of now.

In case anyone else needs it - here is it:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'so_status_completed', 10, 3);

function so_status_completed($order_id)
{

$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$status=$order->get_status();

$order->get_items();
                if ( count( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {


foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    // Here you get your data

    $deposititemid = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_Deposititemid', true ); 
    $appointment=wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Appointment ID', true ); 

wc_update_order_item_meta( $deposititemid, 'Remaining Order Status', $status);
    
                }}}
```